# grep limit depth of file path

Tags: bash, grep, zsh

I save directories I use a lot as variables (e.g. ~saved). When I use these directories in my grep I get the full file-path (that is from the root).

```
grep -r foo ~saved
```

yields

```
/a/very/long/and/complex/file/path/to/a/file/that/contains/foo.xml <foo>
```

This is hard to read and is largely unhelpful. What I would like is something like the following or anything equivalently brief.

```
~saved/contains/foo.xml <foo>
```

Comment: The `~` expansion is done in the console grep never sees the `~`. What you can do is use `tr` to replace what you want.

Comment: `grep -r foo path|sed 's/^commonPath/prefix/'`

Comment: for the above situation what would commonPath and prefix be?

Comment: @Kent How do I get around the expansion of ~saved having \ characters?

Comment: @kent please post grep -r foo ~shared| sed "s:$shared/:shared/:" as an answer because that was the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -r foo path| sed "s:$(~shared)/:shared/:"
```

you can post-process the grep output.

Comment: first path should be ~shared

Comment: @CynicalOptimist ok. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much what exactly `~saved` refers to, here's a shot in the dark:

```
grep -r foo ~saved | sed "s/$(~saved)/~saved/g"
```

Comment: because saved is a path sed parses the "/" incorrectly, you have to use the ":" seperators.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood the question...

Try this:

```
path=$(echo ~saved|sed -re 's/\//\\\//g'); grep -r foo ~saved |  sed -re "s/$path/\~saved/g"
```

Example:

```
path=$(echo ~root|sed -re 's/\//\\\//g'); grep -r find ~root |  sed -re "s/$path/\~root/g"
~root/.subversion/config:###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR, 
~root/test-all.sh:for i in $(find ~root -type d | grep load); do
~root/.siegerc:# requested by the server. If it finds a match, it will send
```

Comment: `-o, --only-matching
       Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.` This has no influence on the filename being printed.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I thought the long path was coming from the match not the filename.

Comment: Nice effort but the solution offered by @Kent is by far the simplest I got it working with grep -r foo path| sed "s:$saved/:saved/"